# What should I do about "No Directionality widget found" during testing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm trying to test my Widget that contains a [MarkdownBody](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_markdown/latest/flutter_markdown/MarkdownBody-class.html) via:

```
testWidgets('Answer displayed correctly',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(MyWidget("text")));
...
```

I'm getting the error:

```
The following assertion was thrown building MarkdownBody(state: _MarkdownWidgetState#9550f):
No Directionality widget found.
RichText widgets require a Directionality widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a Directionality ancestor was:
  RichText
The ownership chain for the affected widget is: "RichText ← Wrap ← Column ← MarkdownBody ← Center ←
  Padding ← Expanded ← Row ← Column ← DecoratedBox ← ⋯"
Typically, the Directionality widget is introduced by the MaterialApp or WidgetsApp widget at the
top of your application widget tree. It determines the ambient reading direction and is used, for
example, to determine how to lay out text, how to interpret "start" and "end" values, and to resolve
EdgeInsetsDirectional, AlignmentDirectional, and other *Directional objects.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MarkdownBody
```

Obviously, this error appears here because I test my Widget directly instead of using it within MaterialApp or WidgetsApp. It looks to me like a lot of extra code when I always have to put Directionality Widgets into my test code. Is there a way to avoid typing a lot of extra test code to deal with the Directionality?

Comment: what you mean by "a lot of extra test code"? all you need is to add `Directionality` widget as a parent

Comment: @pskink : I seems that need to do that whenever testing something that involves the MarkdownBody down the tree.